# Planning flights for a special route

Tags: plotting, geography

I want to plan a world trip with *Mathematica*. So I already have the dataset with all the cities I want to visit and the tour (with the command `FindShortestTour`).
So now I want to know how to come from one City to the other (flight, train, bus, ...)
Do you know if *Mathematica* has a command which can show me the way with the different transportations?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: [`TravelDirections`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TravelDirections.html). It has been introduced in version 10.3.

Comment: I thought you were joking. Incredible.

Comment: `TravelDirections` is very useful. Up until now i have had to download XML files from open street maps to plot travel paths after holidays

Comment: Thanks for your comments :) Does somebody also know a way without 10.3?

Comment: The [Wolfram Development Platform](https://develop.wolframcloud.com) is on version 10.3. Also you may want to edit your question adding the version you are using.